# "Filename argument required" warning when running shell command from bash_profile

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, sh

I'm customizing my .bash_profile in my Mac's Terminal. I want to make a function that either runs a ruby file or opens it in a text editor, depending on my arguments.

I'm very new to doing anything more with Terminal than just installing stuff.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
scratchpad(){
if [ $1 = run ]; then
    ruby ~/Programming/ruby/scratchpad.rb
    .
else
    open -a $1 ~/Programming/ruby/scratchpad.rb
    .
fi
}
```

It works, successfully opening or running the script, but it gives me this error:

```
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

Comment: What did you expect the `.` to do?

Comment: `.` is the same as the `source` command (used for loading scripts into the _current_ shell environment); it requires a filename argument; since you're not providing one, you're getting the stated error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `.` lines:

```
scratchpad(){
  if [ $1 = run ]; then
    ruby ~/Programming/ruby/scratchpad.rb
  else
    open -a $1 ~/Programming/ruby/scratchpad.rb
  fi
}
```

In the shell, `.` is a builtin command in its own right, an alias for "source", which is used to read in a shell script and execute its commands in the current shell rather than spawning a subshell, typically used for scripts that set environment variables that you want to use later

```
. set_env.sh
```

The error message you get is complaining that you haven't provided the file name argument that the `.` command expects.

Comment: Thank you! In my infinite wisdom, I assumed `.` was a `break` statement or something.